# Navigation bar Right to Left - Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, navigation-drawer

How can I make a Navigation Drawer slide from Right to Left, below is XAML code, I tried to use `FlowDirection`, but it's changing the entire app direction, I want the effect to be only on the Navigation Drawer.:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Via.Views"
            FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
            x:Class="Via.Views.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage
            FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
            >
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AccidentReports />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, i could be wrong!

Comment: What could be the best approach @G.hakim ?

Answer (score 1):

We tried doing this also and Xamarin.Forms doesn't support it. We used a plugin that does, [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit). It takes more customization (since it's not a native x.forms behavior) but it will get the job done. We're using it in a xamarin.forms app in both app stores right now.